# How to count an item with a specific string in an Excel VBA listbox?

Tags: excel, vba, count, listbox, instance

I have here a simple form that displays items from a sheet through a ListBox1 during Initialize.

[image: form]

This is this the image of raw data:

[image: sheet excel]

This is the text data:

```
Name        Letter
James       A
Mary        A
Robert      B
Patricia    C
John        C
Jennifer    C
Michael     D
Jennifer    E
David       E
```

This is my whole simple code. What I would like to achieve is to count the instance/occurrence of the letters shown in ListBox1. I know that we can use the count function for ranges from a sheet. But I would like to explore if we can count an instance of a dynamic data with a specific string in a listbox. In my code below, I have the idea but I don’t know how to complete it.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Me.ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .ColumnHeads = True
        .ColumnWidths = "80;80"
        .RowSource = "Sheet9!A2:B10"
    End With
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim iCountA As Integer, iCountB As Integer, iCountC As Integer, iCountD As Integer, iCountE As Integer
        
        For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
            'if i string in column Color is equal to "A" then show the count as iCountA in labelA of the form
            'if i string in column Color is equal to "B" then show the count as iCountB in labelB of the form
            'if i string in column Color is equal to "C" then show the count as iCountC in labelC of the form
            'if i string in column Color is equal to "D" then show the count as iCountD in labelD of the form
            'if i string in column Color is equal to "E" then show the count as iCountE in labelE of the form
        Next
        Me.labelA.Caption = iCountA
        Me.labelB.Caption = iCountB
        Me.labelC.Caption = iCountC
        Me.labelD.Caption = iCountD
        Me.labelE.Caption = iCountE
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Count Unique Items

[image]

**Main**

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    
    Dim Ids() As Variant: Ids = VBA.Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
    
    With Me
        Dim Labels() As Variant:
        Labels = VBA.Array(.labelA, .labelB, .labelC, .labelD, .labelE)
        Dim dict As Object
        With .ListBox1
            .ColumnCount = 2
            .ColumnWidths = "80;40"
            .ColumnHeads = True
            .RowSource = "Sheet1!A2:B10"
            Set dict = DictColumnCount(.List, 1) ' 2nd column
        End With
        Dim n As Long, iStr As String
        For n = 0 To UBound(Ids)
            iStr = Ids(n)
            If dict.Exists(iStr) Then
                Labels(n).Caption = iStr & ": " & dict(iStr)
            Else
                Labels(n).Caption = ""
            End If
        Next n
    End With

End Sub
```

**The Help**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the unique values and their count from a column
'               ('ColumnIndex') of a 2D array ('Data') in the keys and items
'               of a dictionary.
' Remarks:      Error values and blanks are excluded.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function DictColumnCount( _
    ByVal Data As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal ColumnIndex As Variant) _
As Object
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' case-insensitive
    
    Dim c As Long
    
    If IsMissing(ColumnIndex) Then
       c = LBound(Data, 2)
    Else
       c = CLng(ColumnIndex)
    End If
    
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1)
        Key = Data(r, c)
        If Not IsError(Key) Then
            If Len(Key) > 0 Then
                dict(Key) = dict(Key) + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next r
   
    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Function
    
    Set DictColumnCount = dict

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks! This is useful for a column that has an item/list with ampersand character..

Answer (score 3):

Use a [Dictionary Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object)

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim dCount As Object, i As Long, sName, ctr
    Set dCount = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
     
    With Me.ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .ColumnHeads = True
        .ColumnWidths = "80;80"
        .RowSource = "Sheet9!A2:B10" 'Sheet9
        For i = 1 To .ListCount
            sName = "label" & Trim(.List(i - 1, 1))
            dCount(sName) = dCount(sName) + 1
        Next
    End With
   
    For Each ctr In Me.Controls
        If dCount.exists(ctr.Name) Then
            ctr.Caption = dCount(ctr.Name)
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

**Alternative without Dictionary**

This approach uses

- a tricky `CountLetters()` function as combination of `Count` & `Match`, where the `letter` variable reflects letters A-E, and
- assigns the results *directly* to the five labels "LabelA", "LabelB", .. "LabelE" via `Me.Controls(..).Caption`:

```
        letter = Chr(64 + i)
        With Application
            Me.Controls(LABELPREFIX & letter).Caption = _
                letter & ": " & .count(.Match(arr, Array(letter), 0))
        End With
```

---

**UserForm Code**

```
Option Explicit
Private LetterRng As Range

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'1) define data ranges
    DataSettings LetterRng
'2) count letters & write to Labels A..E
    countLetters LetterRng.Value2
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Layout()
'Purp:  define base layout outside Userform's Init proc
'Note:  defining calculated RowSource see (1) Sub DataSettings !
    Me.Caption = "Count Letters"
    With Me.ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .ColumnHeads = True
        .ColumnWidths = "80;80"
    End With
End Sub
```

**Help procedures called from `Userform_Initialize` procedure**

**(1) DataSettings**

Calculates the actually needed ranges for *letters column* and for the listboxes `.RowSource`:

```
Sub DataSettings(rng As Range)
'Purp:  user defined settings for letter and listbox ranges
'       returns letter range (via argument by reference)
'Note:  considers lastrow in 1st column (assuming letters in 2nd column)
'a) define range of letter column
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")      ' << change as needed
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("B2:B" & lastRow)
    End With
'b) define listbox rowsource
    With Me.ListBox1                            ' << change as needed
        .RowSource = _
            rng.Offset(0, -1).Resize(, 2).Address(External:=True)
    End With
End Sub
```

**2) Essential routine `countLetters`**

- `Match()` results in (position) `1` for each finding in the one-position base array `Array(letter)` and errors for all non-findings
- `Count()` neglects errors and thus is able to return the correct number of findings per letter

```
Sub countLetters(arr, Optional maxLetters As Long = 5)
'Purp.: count letters & write result directly to related label
'       (LabelA, LabelB,.. LabelE)
    Const LABELPREFIX As String = "Label"
    
    Dim letter As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To maxLetters
        letter = Chr(64 + i)                ' here: A .. E
        With Application
            Me.Controls(LABELPREFIX & letter).Caption = _
                letter & ": " & .count(.Match(arr, Array(letter), 0))
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```